# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when decoding with NSKeyedUnarchiver

Tags: objective-c, macos

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the decodeObjectForKey: call. I would be grateful if anyone could spot an obvious bug here:

```
- (NSData *)serialize:(id <NSCoding>)object {
  NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
  NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
  [archiver setOutputFormat:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0];
  [archiver encodeObject:object forKey:@"myobject"];
  [archiver finishEncoding];
  return data;
}

- (id)deserialize:(NSData *)data {
  NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
  unarchiver.delegate = self;
  id object = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"myobject"];
  [unarchiver finishDecoding];
  return object;
}
```

The NSCoding protocol is implemented like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
  self = [super init];
  if (self != nil) {
    _fields = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"fields"];
    _entries = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"entries"];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
  [aCoder encodeObject:_fields forKey:@"fields"];
  [aCoder encodeObject:_entries forKey:@"entries"];
}
```

I can't use +unarchiveObjectWithData: because I need to set a delegate to update deserialized objects:

```
- (id)unarchiver:(NSKeyedUnarchiver *)unarchiver didDecodeObject:(id)object {
  if([[object class] isSubclassOfClass:[LCEntity class]]) {
    [object setStore:_store];
  }
  return nil;
}
```

I'm using ARC - so don't worry about memory management issues.

Comment: Please post your implementation of the NSCoding protocol.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for the crash? Also, your call to `-isSubclassOfClass:` is unnecessarily verbose. You can say `[object isKindOfClass:[LCEntity class]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you actually use an archiver/unarchiver that way? Typically you have a root object that's encoded, and it encodes the rest of the graph. Try using the following:

```
- (NSData *)serialize:(id <NSCoding>)object {
    return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object];
}

- (id)deserialize:(NSData *)data {
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
}
```

Of course, at this point the -serialize: and -deserialize: methods are pretty superfluous. Their callers should just call NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver directly.

---

Alternatively, your encoded object, or one of its sub-objects, may have a bad implementation of `-initWithCoder:`. This should be apparent in the stack trace.

Comment: I was actually wondering the same, I am looking at the docs it should work with encode as well.

Comment: I added more details on why I can't use the convenience methods. Also checked all my initWithCoder: methods - it doesn't seem to be the  source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by always returning the object in my NSKeyedUnarchiverDelegate:

```
- (id)unarchiver:(NSKeyedUnarchiver *)unarchiver didDecodeObject:(id)object {
  if([[object class] isSubclassOfClass:[LCEntity class]]) {
    [object setStore:_store];
  }
  return object;
}
```

A bit weird as Apple's docs state you should return nil if you don't want to replace the object...